# phpdoc web interface: Undefined offset: 1 in <PHPDOCDIR>\src\phpDocumentor\Console\Input\ArgvInput.php

Tags: phpdoc

I've installed phpdoc using the installer.php file, and when I open phpdoc.php from wamp (localhost/phpDocumentor/bin/phpdoc.php) I get this error:

```
 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\Tools\Programming\WebsiteBuilding\WAMP\wamp2.2e\www\phpDocumentor\src\phpDocumentor\Console\Input\ArgvInput.php on line 52
```

I set `register argc argv` to `true` in my WAMP php - settings, but I still get this.

What am I doing wrong?

Snapshot of the error:

[image: Error snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPDoc is intended for command line usage. The error you get means that you didn't provide an argument. This means you can't *call* PHPDoc via webserver, you can only *view* the generated docs.

A typical call to `phpdoc` under Windows looks like that (on the **command line**):

```
phpdoc.bat -d src -t docs
```

Where `src` is the directory that your sources are and `docs` the directory where the documentation should be generated.

For more instructions see the [PHPDoc installer documentation](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/installation/using-installer.html#instructions).

Comment: phpdoc 1.x had a web interface with it... phpdoc2 does not.

Comment: I didn't know that. But still: the script Dori tries to run is intended for the command line. Do you agree?

Comment: Oh, indeed you are correct.  I was making a separate distinction, in case phpdoc 1.x experience was making for incorrect expectations from 2.x ;-)

Comment: Yes, you're right, and @ashnazg thanks for clarifying. The documentation I found did mention a web interface so I was wondering why it didn't work, but I'm using v2